# Why we started using .html instead of .htm?

Tags: html, url

I have read that initially there was .htm because file name extensions were only 3 characters long so, it was not possible to use .html

Even today we are using 3 character name extensions for example .php , .css and if we look at javascript it is .js only two characters long.

Second thing I have read is that there is no difference between these two.

I know different people have asked about difference between them on stackoverflow, I am not asking the difference. `My question is if both are same than what was the reason that we started using .html instead of .htm`

Comment: Because if the language is called HTML, `.html` makes more sense than `.htm`

Comment: .html was used from the beginning on unix and other systems which didn't have the three-letter limitation.

Comment: You have it backwards. Initially it was .html. Windows couldn't use more than three characters as a file extension so Windows users had to shorten it to .htm. The web was created on Unix which, along with BSD, has no issues with longer file extensions.

Comment: Why closed? This is not opinion-based at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML was developed on UNIX systems which were not limited to three letter extensions. The [first website](http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html) used `.html`.

The `l` was dropped when people wrote HTML on DOS/Windows machines that predated Windows 95.

When people stopped using those systems, they stopped dropping the `l`.

Comment: but, still we could have countinued to use .htm because we can use 3 character long extenions for example .php , .css and if we look at javascript it is .js only two characters long

Comment: @Taimour: But `html` is the more-correct extension.

Comment: @Taimour: .html was defacto standard from the beginning, since it was used on unix and other systems. DOS was the only system which had the three letter limitation.

Comment: It's because when the web started, it was mostly all UNIX machines and `.html` was the default extension. It wasn't until people started using DOS and Windows webservers that it was changed to `.htm`, so once the 3 character extension limit was lifted, it was only natural to go back to the origins of `.html`

Comment: Rephrased the answer to make it clearer and added a comment about the first website.

Comment: @user13286 It was never "changed" to .htm and there was no limit to lift. It's that Unix could handle any file extension and Windows couldn't.

Comment: @Rob if there was no limit, why didn't DOS/Windows webservers use .html extension? It's called an 8.3 filename. 3 characters was the limit for the extension.

Comment: @user13286 The limitation was self imposed on Windows by Windows. There was, and is, no limit to any other server or operating system or by any internet standard. (Technically there is a limit of, I'm guessing, 255 characters.)

Comment: @Rob I'm not referring to "any other server or operating system," I am referring to DOS/early Windows which had a 3 character extension limit, thus the introduction of the `.htm` file extension.

Comment: Also it should be noted that file extensions are completely meaningless when it comes to the contents of the file. Any file can have a `.htm` extension, and a HTML file could have any other extension. Web servers can be configured to treat any extension as any file type.

Comment: @user13286 The question did not restrict itself to Windows or DOS.

Comment: @Rob No, of course not, it asked why, and this is why. A limit is a limit, self-imposed or not.

Comment: @user13286 The question was, why did we start using .html and the truth is we started with .html. There is no limit on name extensions on the web.

Comment: @Rob — Since DOS is the reason `.htm` was ever used, it is relevant to the question.

Comment: @Quentin Yes but the question makes a false assumption.